# Condition Based Custom Flag

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-wrangling, eda

I've a dataset

| id | ref | name | conditionCol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | a | no_error |
| 1 | 456 | b | error |
| 1 | 789 | c | no_error |
| 2 | 231 | d | no_error |
| 2 | 312 | e | no_error |
| 2 | 546 | f | no_error |
| 3 | 645 | g | error |
| 3 | 879 | h | error |
| 4 | 789 | i | no_error |
| 4 | 978 | j | no_error |

I'm trying to create a custom `error_flag`, condition being:

- for each unique `id` column elements
- if any row in the `conditionCol` has the keyword `error`, then
- for each row should be flagged as `yes` in the `error_flag`
- if for any element in `id` column
- not even a single row has the keyword `error` in  `conditionCol` column, then
- for each row should be flagged as `no` in the `error_flag`

E.g. For `id`:1, all the values of `error_flag` is yes, as for id value 1, row #2 of `conditionCol` has `error`

| id | ref | name | conditionCol | error_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | a | no_error | yes |
| 1 | 456 | b | error | yes |
| 1 | 789 | c | no_error | yes |

But, for `id`:2, all the values of `error_flag` is no, as for id value 2, no row of `conditionCol` has `error`

| id | ref | name | conditionCol | error_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 231 | d | no_error | no |
| 2 | 312 | e | no_error | no |
| 2 | 546 | f | no_error | no |

Similarly for `id` value 3 & 4:

| id | ref | name | conditionCol | error_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 645 | g | no_error | no |
| 3 | 879 | h | no_error | no |
| 4 | 789 | i | error | yes |
| 4 | 978 | j | error | yes |

And final output being:

| id | ref | name | conditionCol | error_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | a | no_error | yes |
| 1 | 456 | b | error | yes |
| 1 | 789 | c | no_error | yes |
| 2 | 231 | d | no_error | no |
| 2 | 312 | e | no_error | no |
| 2 | 546 | f | no_error | no |
| 3 | 645 | g | no_error | no |
| 3 | 879 | h | no_error | no |
| 4 | 789 | i | error | yes |
| 4 | 978 | j | error | yes |

*Update*:

If you wish to play around with the dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

id_col = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4]
ref_col = [123,456, 789, 231, 312, 546, 645, 879, 789, 978]
name_col = ['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
conditionCol = ['no_error', 'error', 'no_error', 'no_error', 'no_error', 'no_error', 'no_error', 'no_error', 'error', 'error']
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(id_col, ref_col, name_col, conditionCol), columns=['id','ref','name','conditionCol'])
df
```

update2: Is there a way to work with thresholds, i.e.:

- current question: atleast one occurrence of keyword `error` in conditionCol column for each individual unique `id`s, then the value in `error_flag` would be `yes` for all the rows in that id value
- atleast 4 or atleast 5 occurrence of keyword `error` in conditionCol column for unique `id`s, then only the value in `error_flag` would be `yes` for all the rows in that id value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with test if at least one value `error` per groups by `id`:

```
m = df['id'].isin(df.loc[df['conditionCol'].eq('error'), 'id'])
#alternative
#m = df['conditionCol'].eq('error').groupby(df['id']).transform('any')
df['error_flag'] = np.where(m, 'yes', 'no')

print (df)
   id  ref name conditionCol error_flag
0   1  123    a     no_error        yes
1   1  456    b        error        yes
2   1  789    c     no_error        yes
3   2  231    d     no_error         no
4   2  312    e     no_error         no
5   2  546    f     no_error         no
6   3  645    g     no_error         no
7   3  879    h     no_error         no
8   4  789    i        error        yes
9   4  978    j        error        yes
```

Comment: Trying to expand solution's scope and making it dynamic, is there a way to set a threshold to take decision on yes/no in the `error_flag` column? E.g. currently even a single occurrence of keyword `error` in the `conditionCol` sets all the rows to yes. But if we want to see if the keyword `error` occurs at least x-times, then only the `error_flag` column should have yes, otherwise no

Comment: @JaspreetSingh Yes, then change `m = df['conditionCol'].eq('error').groupby(df['id']).transform('any')` to `m = df['conditionCol'].eq('error').groupby(df['id']).transform('sum').lt(x)` and `x` is threshold

Comment: Yes, it works (also had to switch yes/no and make it as `df['error_flag'] = np.where(m, 'no', 'yes')` ) but it worked. You gave me a lot of new methods to learn today, thanks :)