# Pandas Groupby Operation For Condition Based Feature Creation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, exploratory-data-analysis

Having difficulties to create a feature based on the some groupby + conditions

The data that I've looks similar to

|  | ir_id | pli | pli_missing | err_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | name1 | 1.0 | no | UNKNOWN |
| 1 | name1 | 2.0 | no | NaN |
| 2 | name1 | 3.0 | no | NaN |
| 3 | name1 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN |
| 4 | name2 | 4.0 | no | NaN |
| 5 | name2 | 5.0 | no | NaN |
| 6 | name2 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN |
| 7 | name3 | 6.0 | no | NaN |
| 8 | name3 | 7.0 | no | NaN |
| 9 | name3 | 8.0 | no | NaN |
| 10 | name3 | 9.0 | no | UNKNOWN |
| 11 | name4 | 10.0 | no | NaN |
| 12 | name4 | 11.0 | no | NaN |
| 13 | name4 | 12.0 | no | NaN |
| 14 | name5 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN |
| 15 | name5 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN |
| 16 | name5 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN |
| 17 | name5 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN |

I want to **groupby at ir_id** such that I can create `err_flag` column which is:

- **type1**: atleast 1 row having value "UNKNOWN" in `err_type` column, and also "yes" in `pli_missing`

|  | ir_id | pli | pli_missing | err_type | err_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | name2 | 4.0 | no | NaN | type1 |
| 5 | name2 | 5.0 | no | NaN | type1 |
| 6 | name2 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN | type1 |

|  | ir_id | pli | pli_missing | err_type | err_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | name5 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN | type1 |
| 15 | name5 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN | type1 |
| 16 | name5 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN | type1 |
| 17 | name5 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN | type1 |

- **type2**: atleast 1 row having value "UNKNOWN" in `err_type` column, and also "no" in `pli_missing`

|  | ir_id | pli | pli_missing | err_type | err_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | name3 | 6.0 | no | NaN | type2 |
| 8 | name3 | 7.0 | no | NaN | type2 |
| 9 | name3 | 8.0 | no | NaN | type2 |
| 10 | name3 | 9.0 | no | UNKNOWN | type2 |

- **type3**: no row having value "UNKNOWN" in `err_type` column, and also "no" in `pli_missing`

|  | ir_id | pli | pli_missing | err_type | err_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | name4 | 10.0 | no | NaN | type3 |
| 12 | name4 | 11.0 | no | NaN | type3 |
| 13 | name4 | 12.0 | no | NaN | type3 |

- **both_type**: both type1 and type2 error flag, i.e.

|  | ir_id | pli | pli_missing | err_type | err_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | name1 | 1.0 | no | UNKNOWN | both_type |
| 1 | name1 | 2.0 | no | NaN | both_type |
| 2 | name1 | 3.0 | no | NaN | both_type |
| 3 | name1 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN | both_type |

Which results in final O/p as:

|  | ir_id | pli | pli_missing | err_type | err_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | name1 | 1.0 | no | UNKNOWN | both_type |
| 1 | name1 | 2.0 | no | NaN | both_type |
| 2 | name1 | 3.0 | no | NaN | both_type |
| 3 | name1 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN | both_type |
| 4 | name2 | 4.0 | no | NaN | type1 |
| 5 | name2 | 5.0 | no | NaN | type1 |
| 6 | name2 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN | type1 |
| 7 | name3 | 6.0 | no | NaN | type2 |
| 8 | name3 | 7.0 | no | NaN | type2 |
| 9 | name3 | 8.0 | no | NaN | type2 |
| 10 | name3 | 9.0 | no | UNKNOWN | type2 |
| 11 | name4 | 10.0 | no | NaN | type3 |
| 12 | name4 | 11.0 | no | NaN | type3 |
| 13 | name4 | 12.0 | no | NaN | type3 |
| 14 | name5 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN | type1 |
| 15 | name5 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN | type1 |
| 16 | name5 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN | type1 |
| 17 | name5 | NaN | yes | UNKNOWN | type1 |

---

***dataset used:***

```py
custom_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'ir_id':['name1', 'name1', 'name1', 'name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name2', 'name3', 'name3', 'name3', 'name3', 'name4', 'name4', 'name4', 'name5', 'name5', 'name5', 'name5']
    , 'pli': [1,       2,       3,       np.nan,  4,       5,       np.nan,  6,       7,       8,       9,       10,      11,      12,      np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan]
    , 'pli_missing': ["no","no","no","yes","no","no","yes","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes"]
    , 'err_type': ["UNKNOWN",np.nan,np.nan,"UNKNOWN",np.nan,np.nan,"UNKNOWN",np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,"UNKNOWN",np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,"UNKNOWN","UNKNOWN","UNKNOWN","UNKNOWN"]
    , 'err_flag': ["both_type", "both_type", "both_type", "both_type", "type1", "type1", "type1", "type2", "type2", "type2", "type2", "type3", "type3", "type3", "type1", "type1", "type1", "type1"]
})

custom_df
```

---

**PS**
Earlier [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71554318/condition-based-custom-flag) can't handle cases for *ir_id = name5*

Comment: What err_flag is expected at name5? Due to your description I'd expect to see there type1, but you marked it as both_type. Have I missed something?

Comment: you're right, it must be type1. Corrected the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we could apply here sort of *categorical* logic. Here's what I mean.

Let's say `['type3','type1','type2','both_types']` are verbal representatives of codes `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. Why this order? As I can see, `type3` is sort of a default value. `type1` and `type2` are equal by nature, but we have somehow to differ them. So let's follow their names and say that `type1` is 1 and `type2` is 2. And `both_types` has index 3 as a sum of previos two codes. Now we can separate identifying if a record can be of type 1 or 2, and get their sum as a final output. If a record is neither type 1 nor type 2 kind of error, the sum will result in 0. If there's only one of them, the sum will keep it as is. If a record can be of both types, the sum will show 3.

Let's see how it looks in code:

```
err = custom_df['err_type'] == 'UNKNOWN'
pli = custom_df['pli_missing'] == 'yes'
grouper = custom_df['ir_id']

# with transform get the same dimension as custom_df
type1 = (err & pli).groupby(grouper).transform(any)
type2 = (err & ~pli).groupby(grouper).transform(any)

codes = type1 + 2*type2
categories = ['type3','type1','type2','both_types']
custom_df['err_flag_new'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(codes, categories)
```

Here's what I've got in the end:

[image]

---

**update**

We can look at it this way. Suppose there's a system with some number of independent states. A system can be described as having any combination of them. It can be described mathematically as a *binary code*. For each *independant* state we assing a unique place in this code, where values 1 or 0 are interpreted as a logical answer whether the system has a corresponding state. *Binary* means a sum like this one:

```
state[0]*2^0 + state[1]*2^1 + state[2]*2^2 + state[3]*2^3 + ...
```

In our case we have only 2 independent states `type1` and `type2`. Two others are their combinations: `type3` means neather of them, and `both_types` tells for itself. So we have only first two terms of the sum above, where `state[0]` is a logical value for `type1` and `state[1]` is a logical value for `type2`. That's why I used `codes = type1 + 2*type2` which is equal to `codes = type1 * 2**0 + type2 * 2**1`

As for the order in `['type3','type1','type2','both_types']`, in this list indexes of values resemble the corresponding codes, ie. each type here has the index equal to their binary code. The binary code for `type3` in this model is `0b00` which is zero, for `type1` it is `0b01` which is one, for `type2` - `0b10` which is 2 and for `both_types` it's `0b11` which is equal to 3. These codes are atomatically assigned when creating `Categorical` sequence from `codes`, ie. pandas is using codes as indexes to get corresponding values from the list and place them instead of the codes.

See also [Enum.IntFlag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntFlag) as an abstract realization of this idea, and [Flags in the regular expression module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#flags) as an example of how it can be used.

Comment: Thanks, this solution does the task. However, I'm not able to understand why you performed `codes = type1 + 2*type2`. And any specific reason for the order of categories in the list named `categories`. Some comments could have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. I trust someone else could find a better one, but it seems to arrive at the requested result correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = custom_df.copy()

condlist = [((df['err_type'] == 'UNKNOWN') & (df['pli_missing'] == 'yes')),
            ((df['err_type'] == 'UNKNOWN') & (df['pli_missing'] == 'no'))]

choicelist = ['type1','type2']

df['err_flag'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default='type3')

s = df[df['err_flag'] != 'type3'].groupby('ir_id')['err_flag'].nunique().gt(1)
df.loc[df['ir_id'].isin(s[s].index),'err_flag'] = 'both_type'

df['err_flag'] = df.sort_values(['ir_id','err_flag']).groupby(['ir_id'])\
    ['err_flag'].transform('first')

print(df[['ir_id','err_flag']].drop_duplicates())

    ir_id   err_flag
0   name1  both_type
4   name2      type1
7   name3      type2
11  name4      type3
14  name5      type1

print(df.equals(custom_df))
# True
```

Explanation steps:

- We start with [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). In the `condlist` we store the conditions for `type1` and `type2`, we let `type3` be the default (i.e. neither condition is met), and assign the result to a new column, `err_flag`.
- Next, we select from the `df` only the rows that do not contain `type3` in the new column and use [`df.groubpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then [`.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) to get a count of the unique values for each group (minus a potential `type3` of course).
- Now, any of our filtered groups can only have 2 unique values (`type1` *and* `type2`) or just 1. So, we want to filter using [`.gt(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) to get a boolean `Series` that will have `True` only for the groups that have both. These are the ones we want to overwrite with `both_type`.
- To overwrite the groups mentioned, we filter the `df` again based on the aforementioned `Series` and assign `both_type`.
- In the final step, we sort the `df` on `['ir_id','err_flag']` and group by `ir_id`. Now, we can ask for the `first` value from each group and we wamt to assign this value to the entire group (hence, the use of  [`.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)), thus overwriting any `type3` values that are left (i.e. both `type1` and `type2` will come first, because of the sort).